# Reroute URL parameters to path and keep HTML references working (htaccess)

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL `http://example.com/?r=FOO&c=BAR` which I want to access via `http://example.com/FOO/BAR`. Both parameters are optional. I got this working using this htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(.*)?$ index.php?r=$1&c=$2   [L]
```

However, now I realized that files referenced in my index.php will not load. For example I have a `http://example.com/css/app.css`. With the current rewriting of the URL the browser tries to get `http://example.com/FOO/css/app.css` and receives the actual index.php.

I tried adding `<base href="/">` and `<base href="http://example.com/">`.

I'm stuck here. Anyone knows how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ignore files by adding this condition under your `RewriteBase`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Comment: That was quick. I will mark the answer as correct in 9 Minutes. ;) Thanks